# Is it possible to make a "centralized" MouseEvent?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I have these two MouseEvents, and I want them "centralized" because I have other nodes that will do the same thing. I know that this can be done if you create multiple MouseEvents, but I reckon that there must be a shorter way.

```
public class scMain implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button btnView, btnView2;
@FXML
private HBox hboxView, hboxView2;

public void translateTransition(Node node) {
    TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition();
    translate.setNode(node);
    // ...animation stuff   
    translate.play();
}

public void fadeOffTransition(Node node) {
    FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition();
    fade.setNode(node);
    // ...animation stuff  
    fade.play();
}

public void fadeInTransition(Node node) {
    FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition();
    fade.setNode(node);
    // ...animation stuff  
    fade.play();
}

@FXML
void btnMouseEnter(MouseEvent event) {
    fadeOffTransition(btnView);
    hboxView.setVisible(true);
    translateTransition(hboxView);
}

@FXML
void btnMouseExit(MouseEvent event) {
    fadeInTransition(btnView);
    hboxView.setVisible(false);
}}
```

What I tried but obviously didn't work :

```
@FXML
void btnMouseEnter(MouseEvent event, Node first, Node second) {
    fadeOffTransition(first);
    second.setVisible(true);
    translateTransition(second);
}

@FXML
void btnMouseExit(MouseEvent event, Node first, Node second) {
    fadeInTransition(first);
    second.setVisible(false);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   btnMouseEnter(event, btnView2, hboxView2); //error cannot find symbol
   btnMouseExit(event, btnView2, hboxView2); //error cannot find symbol
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: [mcve] please demonstrating what you are after and how it doesn't work

Comment: It's probably better to register the mouse events in Java (for example, in the controller's `initialize()` method) instead of in FXML in this scenario. That way you can use loops, etc., to do the same thing for multiple nodes. You almost certainly don't want a single event handler for multiple nodes; that is a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Register the event handler in the `intialize()` method, instead of in the FXML. Remove the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseExit` attributes from the FXML file, and modify the controller as follows:

```
void btnMouseEnter(Node first, Node second) {
    fadeOffTransition(first);
    second.setVisible(true);
    translateTransition(second);
}


void btnMouseExit(Node first, Node second) {
    fadeInTransition(first);
    second.setVisible(false);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   btnView2.setOnMouseEnter(e -> btnMouseEnter(btnView2, hboxView2));
   btnView2.setOnMouseExit(e -> btnMouseExit(btnView2, hboxView2));
}
```

You can also make the obvious reductions in code, e.g.:

```
private void registerMouseHandlers(Button button, Node target) {
    button.setOnMouseEnter(e -> btnMouseEnter(button, target));
    button.setOnMouseExit(e -> btnMouseExit(button, target));
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    registerMouseHandlers(btnView, hboxView);
    registerMouseHandlers(btnView2, hboxView2);
}
```

And if you have a fairly large number of these, it might also be more efficient (in terms of lines of code) to do

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    List<Button> buttons = List.of(btnView, btnView2);
    List<Node> targets = List.of(hboxView, hboxView2);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < buttons.size() ; i++) {
        registerMouseHandlers(buttons.get(i), targets.get(i));
    }
}
```

You could also consider creating a [custom component](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) encapsulating your button and hbox, which simply implements the event handlers for a single button-hbox pair, and then including them in the FXML using `fx:include`.